# How to kill the main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Strange issue. I kill the main thread, but when the program ends, it still processes the code after `this.Close()`.

Any ideas on how to stop that?

```
MessageBox.Show("Servers overloaded. Exiting.");
this.Close();
//...other code that processes even after it closes...
```

Comment: How do you kill the main thread? Thread.Abort()?

Comment: Its a desktop app. Im using this.Close() to kill the main thread. I only have a single thread running.

Comment: He's probably using WinForms.

Answer (score 9):

Closing the window does not stop the thread.

You can use [Environment.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx) to shutdown immediately.

Comment: No, you shouldn't.  You should call `Close` and `return` to perform a graceful exit.

Comment: You shouldn't, but the OP asked how to kill the main thread. Close and return does not do that. (Nor does Abort actually.) As far as I know, the only (managed) way to immediately kill the main thread is to immediately kill the process.

Comment: I didn't say this was a good idea - but that would be the proper way to actually KILL it.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike ASP.Net's `Response.End()`, calling `Close` will not abort the thread.

You need to add `return;` after calling `Close()` to exit the method.

Comment: But that begs the question, why is there any code after the Close() method if you don't want to execute it? Putting a return after Close() will just end up causing compiler warnings about unreachable code.

Comment: This won't prevent code outside the form from running, though - I agree this is a better approach, but it doesn't answer the question...

Answer (score 2):

Why would it stop at `Close()`? It is still going to exit your method - most things like `Close()` are going to involve sending something to the windows message queue and having it processed. If you need to exit *NOW*, then perhaps `Environment.FailFast`...